# datetime not returning correct value

Tags: javascript

Using only JS Write a function that converts user entered date formatted as M/D/YYYY to a format required by an API (YYYYMMDD). The parameter "userDate" and the return value are strings.

For example, it should convert user entered date "12/31/2014" to "20141231" suitable for the API.

I have wrote:

```
    function formatDate(userDate) {
  // format from M/D/YYYY to YYYYMMDD
  var myDate = new Date(userDate);

  var day = myDate.getDay(); 
  var month = myDate.getMonth(); 
  var year = myDate.getFullYear();

  var d = day.toString();
  var m = month.toString();
  var y = year.toString();

return y + m + d;
}

console.log(formatDate("12/31/2014"));
```

but this is returning: `2014113`
should it not return '20141231'

Thanks to @gurvinder372 by +1 I was able to get '20141231'
but the answer is telling me iv passed 0 out of 4...Ive failed on:

```
Example case: Wrong answer 
  Two-digit month and day: Wrong answer 
  One-digit day: Wrong answer 
  One-digit month: Wrong answer
```

Comment: When you've got that fixed, try "1/1/2014" to find something you've forgotten to do ;)

Comment: and would that be it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Months in `Date` are counted from `0`, so this:

```
myDate.getMonth();
```

will return `0` for January and so on.

Moreover this:

```
var day = myDate.getDay();
```

represents, the day of the week counted from `0`, so it should be replaced with this:

```
var day = myDate.getDate();
```

For one-digit values, you need to check if it's less than `10` and conditionally prepend it with `0`. So the final form of this should be:

```
function formatDate(userDate) {
  // format from M/D/YYYY to YYYYMMDD
  var myDate = new Date(userDate);

  var day = myDate.getDate(); 
  var month = myDate.getMonth() + 1; 
  var year = myDate.getFullYear();

  var d = +day.toString() < 10 ? '0' + day.toString() : day.toString();
  var m = +month.toString() < 10 ? '0' + month.toString() : month.toString();
  var y = year.toString(); // no need for check one-digit values

return y + m + d;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply but your answer only passes 2 of 4 cases I am still failing   One-digit day: Wrong answer &   One-digit month: Wrong answer ...please see original Q updated

Comment: yes that has passed 4 out of 4 thanks for your help S

Answer (score 0):

> but this is returning: 2014113 should it not return '20141231'

Month starts from `0`

Replace

```
var month = myDate.getMonth();
```

with

```
var month = myDate.getMonth() + 1;
```

If you also need to take care of single-digit padding, then do this as well

```
function padToTwoChar( value )
{
   return ( "0" + value ).slice(-2);
}
```

and your return statement will become

```
return padToTwoChar( y ) + padToTwoChar( m ) + padToTwoChar( d );
```

Comment: ok thanks for the help but I dont understand please see original Q

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps you

```js
function formatDate(userDate) {
    var myDate = new Date(userDate);

    var day = myDate.getDate();
    var month = myDate.getMonth() + 1; // +1 as month starts with o
    var year = myDate.getFullYear();

    var d = (day <= 9) ? '0' + day : day.toString(); // append 0 for single digit
    var m = (month <= 9) ? '0' + month : month.toString(); // append 0 for single digit
    var y = year.toString();

    return y + m + d;
}

console.log(formatDate("1/1/2014"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can even get rid of using `Date` constructor. Parsing with date constructor is usually not recommended unless you are using [ISO-8601 format](https://www.iso.org/iso-8601-date-and-time-format.html) as implementation differs in browsers for other formats.

Here is an example with just string [`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) function.

If you want zero padding for single digit numbers, make use of the `pad()` function which formats `1` as `01`.

```js
function formatDate(userDate) {
  // format from M/D/YYYY to YYYYMMDD
  var dateArray = userDate.split('/');
  var m = +dateArray[0];
  var d = +dateArray[1];
  var y = +dateArray[2];
  
  var pad = function(n){return n >= 10? n : '0'+n};
  // if you want zero padding
  // return '' + pad(y) + pad(m) + pad(d);

return '' + y + m + d;
}

console.log(formatDate("12/31/2014"));
```